# How to configure UseSqlServer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, configuration, dbcontext

I'm trying to configure the app to use my class (derived from `DbContext`) `ApplicationDbContext` to connect to my database. I already made the configuration file `appsetting.json`:

```
"Data": {
    "SportStoreProducts": {
        "ConnectionStrings":"Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=SportStore;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
}
```

I used dependency injection to pass the object implementing `IConfiguration` (which is `appsetting.json`) through Startup construction :

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
}
```

Now I want to use this configuration file in `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup` and use extension method `AddDbContext` to register my `ApplicationDbContext` to use the SQL database (`SportStore`) I assigned in the configuration file :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(***);
}
```

My question is that what should I pass into the `UseSqlServer` method as parameters (***) so it can connect context to the SQL Server database using my supplied configuration property?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings")));
```

for more details see -> [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings)

Answer (score 7):

sorry maybe some late but:

1. Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
2. Add the reference: using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

Answer (score 6):

For .NET 6.0 just do this:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<cursosContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:NombreCadena"));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=your_database_name_here;Trusted_Connection=True;");

Answer (score -1):

FOR .NET 7.0

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer(("DefaultConnection"));
```